# Minimum resistance for a home circuit to not have short circuit

Tags: resistance, short-circuit, appliances

Say the circuit breaks at 10A, and we got 220V like in Europe. If I stick a wire directly from one hole in the outlet to the other, there will be a short circuit. But what is the "treshold resistance" for not having a short circuit? It seems that R = V/I = 22 Ohms would be minimum resistance to not break the circuit. So if this thinking is correct, any appliance should have at the very least 22 Ohms resistance? And finally do some small appliances put in extra resistors just to not cause a short circuit?

Comment: Generally resistors are not used to match the line voltage as they convert the excess energy to heat which must be disposed of, but an exception could be some heating appliances where a motor might be in series with the "power resistor" that is the heating element, or some tiny unisolated power supplies for tiny currents that use a combination of capacitive reactance and some backup resistance to drop the mains voltage to a lower level.

Comment: Counterexample: anything with a transformer will have a *DC* resistance less than 22 ohms. It just has an *impedance* much higher at 50Hz.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It seems that R = V/I = 22 Ohms would be minimum resistance to not break the circuit.

This is correct.

> So if this thinking is correct, any appliance should have at the very least 22 Ohms resistance?

This is an oversimplification. There's much more to circuits than resistors.

A toaster or an incandescent light bulb might be analyzed this way, since it's basically just a resistor.

And there are some books and engineers who like to define the "resistance" of a circuit as the ratio between its operating point voltage and currents. In which case your thought is correct as a tautology.

But something like a TV or a computer will have a switching power supply using the mains power to produce an internal DC voltage (or voltages) that actually power the useful circuits. In these circuits don't mainly dissipate power in resistors at all. They use transformers, diodes, capacitors, inductors, and transistors, mainly (resistors are used to adjust control signals, but very little power should be consumed there). This circuit uses feedback to adjust itself to draw the current it needs to provide power to the internal circuits. This actually means it will behave like it has negative differential resistance --- if the mains voltage goes down, the current draw will go up, at least to a point.

> And finally do some small appliances put in extra resistors just to not cause a short circuit?

This should almost never be necessary.

Comment: Actually, parasitic resistance is responsible for most power dissipation - the exception would be an appliance that exports work in the form of light, motion, radio signals, sound, etc - and even then there are *resistive* losses that can consume anything from a small fraction to a majority of the power used.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, but it's the parasitic resistance of the the diodes, transistors, etc., not a resistor that's been placed in the circuit as a distinct device.